Redefine the command \cite to be able to use an additional syntax
Background
The package amsrefs redefines the command \cite so that one can use the syntax "\cite{book-name}*{optional-argument}" to produce (essentially) the same output as the usual "\cite[optional-argument]{book-name}".
For instance, if the book appears as the fifth entry in the bibliography, the command \cite{book-name}*{pag. 42} outputs "[5, pag. 42]".

What I want to do, and my code
I don't want to use the package amsrefs, but for testing purposes, and as an exercise to learn Tex/Latex, I was trying to redefine the command \cite so that it works normally with the usual syntax, but in addition to that, I want it to work with the new syntax \cite{book-name}*{optional-argument} to give the output as above, where the first parameter is mandatory, and the second one is optional. All of this, of course, without loading the aforementioned package.
In short, I want \cite to be able to support these syntaxes:
\cite{mandatory}             % Already defined by Latex
\cite[optional]{mandatory}   % Already defined by Latex
\cite{mandatory}*{optional}  % Defined by me

I came up with the following code which works (edit: the second syntax actually does not yet work, but for the moment I don't care, I will fix it later):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% My code
\let\cites\cite % use when disabling amsrefs
\let\oldcite\cite

\makeatletter

\def\new@cite#1{\def\fappo{{#1}}\futurelet\tok@cite@custom\@newcite}
\def\@newcite{\ifx\tok@cite@custom*\let\@cchoice 2\else\let\@cchoice 1\fi\execute@cchoice}
\def\execute@cchoice{\ifx\@cchoice 1\@new@cite\else\expandafter\@new@@cite\fi}
\def\@new@cite{\expandafter\oldcite\fappo}
\def\@new@@cite*#1{\expandafter\citeinvert\fappo{#1}}

\let\newcite\new@cite
\def\citeinvert#1#2{\oldcite[#2]{#1}}

\makeatother

\let\cite\newcite
% End of my code

\begin{document}

\noindent The syntax \verb+\cite{book}+ yields \cite{greenwade93}.\\
% The syntax \verb+\cite[opt]{book}+ yields \cite[page 42]{greenwade93}.\\ (DOES NOT WORK YET)
The syntax \verb+\cite{book}*{opt}+ yields \cite{greenwade93}*{page 42}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}


Suggestions?
I don't have precise questions, but I was wondering whether there is a way to simplify the code, or if there are different and easier ways.
The main difficulty I have encountered is that whenever I use an \ifx to decide which version of the command to use (depending on how many arguments it should eat), the chosen version of the command always wants to eat the \else or the \fi inside the macro (btw, that is why I am using the first \expandafter). This is the shortest working code that I managed to write, but I struggled a lot, and I suspect I am overlooking some tricks to make things work more smoothly.
I have just started to understand how tokens work, I read this guide by Overleaf, and some other things about \futurelet, etc., but my knowledge is very weak and sparse.

Can you add some testcode demonstrating various use cases of your cite-macro? The code sould, of course, copile ;-) Thank you

Oh sure, thanks for the comment!

You could define the whole syntax using \NewDocumentCommand without any of the ifx and \futurelet testing but I'd strongly recommend defining it as a new command rather than redefining a standard command such as \cite

@MS-SPO I have updated the post with minimal working code and output (I realized that I did not yet implement the second syntax, but that does not matter for now)

Fine. I suggest to listen to David for good reasons ;-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle

Thank you @DavidCarlisle once more :) Your reply answers my question

Comments on my old approach are still welcome though, if anyone wants to share them c:

I would not redefine \cite but if you want to, the desired argument specification may be directly declared with \NewDocumentCommand (see texdoc usrguide)

\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy\oldcite\cite
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\cite{O{}mE{*}{{}}}{%
   \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1#3}{\oldcite}{\oldcite[#1#3]}{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cite{aaa}

\cite[bbb]{aaa}

\cite{aaa}*{ddd}

\cite[fff]{aaa}*{hhh}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{aaa} Some item

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Thank you! I wanted to redefine \cite because I was switching between enabling and disabling amsrefs  to test some other features of the package, and I wanted to avoid warnings and errors without changing the code.

You always get an optional argument…

@egreg yes I used empty defaults as I didn't want the extra complication of checing novalue here as it obscured the main point that the signature is declarable with newdocumentcommand. \cite could/should drop the comma on empty argument anyway

@egreg still I added an empty test to make you happy.

@egreg this is still much simpler than your suggestion:-)

You can’t catch the double optional argument, though.

@egreg I did not intend to, since the arguments have the same meaning if you use both you get both, that seems the most natural interpretation if you do this at all.

@DavidCarlisle thank you for the update. I have used \IfBlankTF in my file, which does not require \ExplSyntaxOn.

I'm afraid that David's answer is not really correct.
You need to check if an optional argument is passed, either as a “classical” one or after *. If not, then you need to call \oldcite without the optional argument or you'd always get “comma and space” after the citation key.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewCommandCopy{\oldcite}{\cite}

\RenewDocumentCommand\cite{ome{*}}
 {
  \lorenzo_cite:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lorenzo_cite:nnn
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_novalue_p:n { #1 } } { \tl_if_novalue_p:n { #3 } }
   {
    \oldcite{#2}
   }
   {
    \oldcite[\tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}{#1} \tl_if_novalue:nF {#3}{#3}]{#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cite{aaa}

\cite[bbb]{aaa}

\cite{aaa}*{ddd}

\cite[fff]{aaa}*{hhh}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{aaa} Some item

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


A modification to print a warning on the console and in the log file if both optional arguments are used.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewCommandCopy{\oldcite}{\cite}

\RenewDocumentCommand\cite{ome{*}}
 {
  \lorenzo_cite:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lorenzo_cite:nnn
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_novalue_p:n { #1 } } { \tl_if_novalue_p:n { #3 } }
   {
    \oldcite{#2}
   }
   {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnT { !\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #1 } } { !\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #3 } }
     {
      \iow_term:e
       {
        WARNING:~double~optional~argument~in~
        \token_to_str:N \cite\c_space_tl
        on~line~\msg_line_context:
       }
     }
    \oldcite[\tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}{#1} \tl_if_novalue:nF {#3}{#3}]{#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cite{aaa}

\cite[bbb]{aaa}

\cite{aaa}*{ddd}

\cite[fff]{aaa}*{hhh}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{aaa} Some item

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

You get the same output as before, but the terminal will show
WARNING: double optional argument in \cite on line on line 42


Thank you for pointing this out. I realized that while testing David Carlisle's code, and I modified it to have no comma, but I did not update the post.
